# jquery mobile dialog appearing with back button

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a site with a user login form shown in a data-rel='dialog' link. Problem is thatthe dialog is appearing in the history when you hit the browser back button. [Screen grabs](http://solomon.ie/so/backbutton.gif) here - a) shows initial not logged in state, b) open dialog after clicking on 'login' button, c) successful login, d) I've hit the back button and get my dialog and e) I've closed the dialog with the default 'x' button, am brought back to my home page, but in a logged out state.

In the code below, the login button/link (to '/php/mobile_login.php' ) is replaced by one's name is login cookies are detected server side.

Also, given that I get back to the home page with data-dom-cache disabled, should it not fetch it from the server again?

Many thanks, Kevin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
<title>title</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;' />


<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery_mobile_global_defaults.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/design/mobile_style.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css' />
</head>
<body>

<div data-role='page' data-dom-cache='false' id='homepage'>

    <div class='header'>
        <div class='logo'></div>
        <div class='login'><a href='/php/mobile_login.php' data-overlay-theme='b' data-transition='none' data-rel='dialog' data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-icon='arrow-r' data-iconpos='right' data-theme='a' data-mini='false'>Login</a></div>
    </div>


    <div class='mobile_content'>
    content
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
<title>title</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/design/mobile_style.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css' />
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery_mobile_global_defaults.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role='dialog'  id='member_login_div' data-overlay-theme='b'>
        <div data-role='header' data-theme='d'>
            <h1>Login</h1>

        </div>

        <div data-role='content' data-theme='c'>
        Login below to apply for jobs with your stored CV (use the desktop version of the site to upload your CV if you have not already done so).
        <form data-ajax='false'  method='POST' action='/php/mobile_do_login.php'>
        <label for='cjloginemail' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Email Address</label>
        <input type='text' name='user_email' id='cjloginemail' value='kevin@solomon.ie' placeholder='Email Address'>
        <label for='cjloginpass' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Password</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='cjloginpass' value='' placeholder='Password'>
        <input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Login'>
        </form>
        <p><a href='/php/mobile_forgot_pass.php'>I forgot my password - email it to me.</a>


    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try closing any dailog onload using `$('.ui-dialog').dialog('close').`

REF: [JQuery mobile - Dailogs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html)

I have read this on the same page, it is weird that it is happening to you.

**

### History & Back button behavior

**

Since dialogs are typically used to support actions within a page, the framework does not include dialogs in the hash state history tracking. This means that dialogs will not appear in your browsing history chronology when the Back button is clicked. For example, if you are on a page, click a link to open a dialog, close the dialog, then navigate to another page, if you were to click the browser's Back button at that point you will navigate back to the first page, not the dialog.

**UPDATE**: Dialog appears on back button in FireFox browser. Works fine on IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: Hi, yes I read that too, hence my posting the question here. It seems very black and white that it should not be there when I hit back. Maybe I'm missing something but don't get your solution - I can see that would close the dialog, but would it stop it appearing within the history?

Comment: you missed to close `</p>` tag after `I forgot my password - email it to me.` but I dont think this is the problem. still working on it.

Comment: Hi, it was valid html 5 without the closing para, but added it in - still the same. I've just used a popup for something else (my first mobile site so everything is new to me) and it does not appear in history - not sure if that relevant

Comment: I tried it on my iPhone 4 and my PC, the dialog doesn't appear when hitting back button. It's weird..What type of smartphone or tablet are you using? EDIT: On Chrome and IE 9 the dialog doesn't appear on back button, but on FireFox it does. So I guess it is a browser issue.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. I'd have done a fiddle thingy but don't know how as yet. I have  samsung galaxy ace, android 2.3. Yes, been doing most of the work on FF/Win XP and it appears on back for both. Just noticed this issue today, so will try IE/Chrome and Opera on ph tomorrow (am home now). Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Seeing what you see IE8/9 and chrome on pc work as expected, FF on pc and Andriod browser and Opera Mobile show dialog in history

Comment: Further testing shows that dialog works as expected (not shown when back used) is one clicks a link within it, not not when I submit a form. found a similar question on the jquey forum and suggest answer was to submit form via javascript - tried that still not working...

Comment: @user602088 I have search form via dialog and it works fine even on FF after submitting the dialog doesn't appear. I am using only JQM nothing else. Can post the latest code so I can test it?

Comment: Is it working for you? As in you can submit a form and it's not in the history? My code is still the same as posted here. I took out the code I tried with the javascript.

Comment: Check out my code. Search button: http://pastebin.com/4LXRYKEv and the dialog: http://pastebin.com/A8V0wxcK

Comment: Omar - thanks to your code, I seem to have solved it. I basically went through your code and mine line by line, and in me dialog I have data-ajax='false' in the <form> tag - removing that fixed it! I'm sure I put that there for a reason, but so far I cannot find any issues with it out. Also from your code I learned about "required" on html5 inputs! Many many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Btw, `required` doesn't work on smartphone, use this script to validate it. http://pastebin.com/2aj0EmL4

Comment: Hi Omar, I forget the exact details, but I think I found that required does work on my samsung, but only for text fields, so yea I want ahead with javascript validation to catch the dropdowns.